# Why is WebStorm not opening any projects?

Tags: windows-7, webstorm

When I normally load WebStorm, it opens my normal project, however it took me to the main menu for some reason as can be seen below.

[image]

I then tried to open my default project - any project for that matter - and was given this error message every single time, for every single project.

[image]

I'm extremely confused because I remember using it earlier and it worked absolutely fine.

### Miscellaneous

**Operating System:** Windows 7 (64 BIT)

**WebStorm Version:** 2016.3.2

Comment: ***Bump*** - If this is migratable to SO, can someone please do it.

Comment: Looks like your installation is broken. I can suggest creating support ticket (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731), providing your idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)